# how to arrange a list of coordinate points in ascending order with respect to origin in python code

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

```
array([[-0.06366486, -2.43028317],
   [ 2.01224776, -0.66531383],
   [ 0.77307079, -0.29340495],
   [ 0.39044409,  0.85686349],
   [-0.92426404,  0.34792792],
   [-0.94323693,  0.69295404],
   [-1.34289803, -1.18248516],
   [-1.19844352, -1.27501523],
   [-0.82092882, -0.76365567],
   [ 0.44943198, -1.0941035 ]])
```

I have array given above , I want to arrange this array points in ascending according to Euclidean distance from origin.

Comment: have a look at the `key` argument of the sort function, if you have looked at the sort function because you want to sort stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

distances to origin can be calculated using `np.linalg.norm`, then by achieving the ordering (*sort_*), the main coordinates *arr* can be sorted based on the distances:

```
to_dist = np.array([0.0, 0.0])

dist = np.linalg.norm(arr - to_dist, axis=1)
# [2.4311169245398436 2.1193828205433505 0.8268765996421271
#  0.9416271172342628 0.9875818209913788 1.1704192444026826
#  1.7893144700130568 1.7498373374008063 1.121202082512221 
#  1.1828151053140006]

sort_ = np.argsort(dist)
# [2 3 4 8 5 9 7 6 1 0]

res = arr[sort_]
# [[ 0.77307079 -0.29340495]
#  [ 0.39044409  0.85686349]
#  [-0.92426404  0.34792792]
#  [-0.82092882 -0.76365567]
#  [-0.94323693  0.69295404]
#  [ 0.44943198 -1.0941035 ]
#  [-1.19844352 -1.27501523]
#  [-1.34289803 -1.18248516]
#  [ 2.01224776 -0.66531383]
#  [-0.06366486 -2.43028317]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

arr= np.array(define your 2 dimension al array here)

print(np.sort(arr))
```

hope this code surely works
Plz reply after using this

Comment: this does not sort on distance but on X and then on Y

Comment: no, it's not working..thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).